# Is there an Java function to grab an entire column in a database?

Tags: java, sql, database

I am trying to grab every column separately, and print every element in that respective column in a database for me to play with later on. Is there a function that can do that?

I have tried to create a function to print the entire column in the console.

```java
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(""jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\b0616717\\workspace\\DATABASE.accdb);
Statement s = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * DATABASE.accdb");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

public void test () throws SQLException {
  for (int x = 1; x < db.rsmd.getColumnCount(); x++) {
    while(rs.next()) {
    String output = rs.getString(x);
    System.out.println(output);
    }
  }
}

I expect it to console print every data in the pertaining column for every column. However, I get only one column printed out.
```

Comment: So if table `ACCDB` has five columns, for example, you want to loop through the entire result set five times, correct?

Comment: Yes if the table ACCDC has 5 columns (A,B,C,D,E) , I would like to print every data under A, then B, so on...

Comment: @ClubSavage So basically you want each column to be a row instead of a column?

Answer (score 2):

you have the loops backwards.  Try this:

```
public void test () throws SQLException {
    int numCols= db.rsmd.getColumnCount();
    while(rs.next()) {
      for (int x = 1; x <= numCols; x++) {
          String output = rs.getString(x);
         System.out.println(output);
      }
    }
  }
```

rs.next() moves to the next row in the result set.  Also can get the column count once before the loop ( more efficient).

Comment: This prints out the element horizontally, whereas I wanted it vertically. As well, I noticed that it takes a long time for the function to complete (given the size of my database), is there another way to work around that?

Comment: use print for the column values and println for a new line.  There is no other way that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the columns to each be a *row* instead of a column when printing, you can use `rs.beforeFirst()` each loop to move the cursor back to the beginning for the `ResultSet`:

```
for (int x = 1; x < db.rsmd.getColumnCount(); x++) {
    rs.beforeFirst(); //Move cursor to start
    while(rs.next()) {
        String output = rs.getString(x);
        System.out.print(output + " "); //Print each value of a column with a space between
    }
    System.out.println(); //Move to next row
}
```

Note that I added a `println` to move to next line, and the `output` no longer uses `println` but rather `print`.

This will go through your `ResultSet` 5 times, but those were the specifications you requested.

Comment: Method `beforeFirst()` in interface `java.sql.ResultSet` may not be supported by the JDBC driver the the OP is using. I couldn't find the JDBC driver details in the question.